# Android Xml Pull Parser Exception occurred when trying to parse a xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, exception

I am getting an exception when I am trying to parse xml file using XML Pull parser. Exception says XmlPullParserException: Unexpected Token( position: TEXT @ 1:2 in java.io.stringreader@40e06970
please give me a solution, my code is,

MainAvtivity.java

```
package com.example.simplexmlpullapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    String str;
    ArrayList<Data> arrdata;
    ArrayList<String> arrayofString;
    String textforinput = "<foo>Hello World!</foo>";
    String parsedData = "";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            readXML();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

private void readXML() throws XmlPullParserException   {

        try {
            Log.i("String","in readXML");
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("countries.xml");
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder total=new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                total.append(line);
            }


            Log.i("String","going in xml parsing"+total);
            xmlParse(total.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


public void xmlParse(String file) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException 
        {
    Log.i("String","going in xml parse");
            boolean demoflag=false;
            Data d=null;

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(file));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        while (eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.i("String","in while");
            switch(eventType)
            {
                case  XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    break; 
                    //System.out.println("Start document");

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("country"))
                        {
                        demoflag=true;
                        d=new Data();
                        }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        if(demoflag)
                        {
                        d.setCountry(xpp.getText().trim());
                        Log.i("country", ""+xpp.getText().trim());
                        }
                        break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("country"))
                        {
                        arrdata.add(d);
                        demoflag=false;
                        }
                        break;
                default : 
                    break;
            }

            eventType=xpp.next();
        }

         arrayofString=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<arrdata.size();i++)
        {
            Data data=arrdata.get(i);
            arrayofString.add(data.getCountry());
            Log.i("parse_example", "country"+data.getCountry());
        }

        }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

country.xml

```
<CountriesList>

    <countries>

        <country>
Afghanistan
        </country>
    </countries>

    <countries>

        <country>
Albania
        </country>
    </countries>

    <countries>

        <country>
Algeria
        </country>
    </countries>

    <countries>
</CountriesList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

country list tag is not ended

```
</CountriesList>
```

you can validate the xml here

http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

**try this xml**

```
<CountriesList>

    <countries>

        <country>
Afghanistan
        </country>
    </countries>

    <countries>

        <country>
Albania
        </country>
    </countries>

    <countries>

        <country>
Algeria
        </country>
    </countries>


</CountriesList>
```

**UPDATE this will print countries in logcat**

```
public void xmlParse(String file) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        Log.i("String", "going in xml parse");
        boolean demoflag = false;
        Data d = null;

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(file));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.i("String", "in while");
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                    demoflag = true;
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                if (demoflag) {
                    Log.i("country", "" + xpp.getText().trim());
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                    demoflag = false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks mate. that tag already has been ended. Then even problem is there.

Comment: problem still persists.

Comment: Thanks Biraj. Done with it.